# How to voltage divide down a single ended analog signal?

Tags: adc, analog, voltage-divider

I have a 0-5V Single ended analog signal coming into an A/D pin on my microcontroller.

The Micro pin can tolerate only 0-3.3V analog signal.

What can I do? Can I just add a simple voltage divider (one resistor in series and other to GND to divide the voltage when it is at 5V down to 3.3V)?

I am concerned.  Isn't this going to add noise from my ground on to this Analog signal of mine and distort it?

UPDATED with a related question:
I also noticed in some circuits some folks add 'Rail to Rail Output Operational Amplifiers (like LMV321 from TI) - how exactly does this help?

Comment: The simple voltage divider places a load on the source of the signal. It also can limit the bandwidth of the A/D converter if the resistor values are high and the distributed capacitance to the A/D input causes an R*C filter effect. The opamp is used for a number of reasons. There can be a gain change (equivalent to the divider) but with resistors that lessen the load on the source. The low impedance output of the opamp can nicely drive the A/D input impedance and the trace connection capacitance without limiting the bandwidth too much. The third big advantage of the (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) opamp is that it can be used to also sum in an offset in the signal translation should that be needed for certain applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting resistive voltage dividers in front of ADC inputs is a rather common design technique. It's done even in highly sensitive instruments (there it will be a somewhat more complicated RC network, but the principle stays the same) so your uC project will be just fine.

But, of course, such questions were asked before:
[How to Convert 0 to 10V analog signal to 0 to 2.5V for ADC input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/how-to-convert-0-to-10v-analog-signal-to-0-to-2-5v-for-adc-input)

Comment: Thanks.
Related question, do you know why "in some circuits some folks add 'Rail to Rail Output Operational Amplifiers (like LMV321 from TI) - how exactly does this help?" (updated the original question too)