# Voltage divider which will work for low and high frequency signals

Tags: voltage-divider

I am using the below circuit (fig1) to step down the voltage, which I found on the internet.
I want this circuit to be operate properly from 1 kHz to 50 MHz. When the input is a square wave. But this circuit work properly in the range of MHz. But when the kHz frequency is given I am getting waveform like this (fig2)[image].

How to calculate the value of R1 and C1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Convert 0 to 10V analog signal to 0 to 2.5V for ADC input?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/how-to-convert-0-to-10v-analog-signal-to-0-to-2-5v-for-adc-input)

Comment: What do you have connected to the 'output' of this divider?

Comment: You need both networks to have identical time-constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of R1 to R2 has to match the impedance ratio of XC1 to XC2. If that condition is met then the network will have a flat frequency response.

So choose R1 to have the right ratio at DC (say 10 x R2) and pick C1 so that its impedance is ten times that of C2. This inevitably means that C2 is ten times C1 in capacitance terms.

Comment: If biasing is applied to the output of this circuit ,will it affect the waveform?

Comment: Any biasing resistors added to the output will be in parallel with R2 and thus the effective value of R2 is lowered and therefore , to keep the frequency response flat, you will need to make C2 higher in capacitance by the same proportion that R2's effective value is reduced.

Comment: yeah i agree, the principle behind this circuit is to match R1C1=R2C2.IF the R1C1>R2C2,The output will be as shown. But does anyone know how did we get the equation R1C1=R2C2?

Comment: To the OP: Basically you have a resistive divider and a capacitive divider. In order for the divider ratio to the same at all frequencies, R1/R2 must equal C2/C1. Hopefully you can see that intuitively. From there, you can re-arrange to get R1C1 = R2C2. Otherwise, the divider ratio will be different for different frequencies.

Comment: yeah but there is a problem.It not only depend on matching R1C1=R2C2. Let's consider we want to step down 25MHz clock signal. and my values are R1=270k,C1=10pF ,R2=200k,C2=13.5pF. According to the above equation R1C1=R2C2=2700ns. But output of this circuit won't be a square wave.It will be greatly effected by the capacitor values.Is there is any relation between time constant and period of input signal?

Comment: With caps that small you need a low capacitance high impedance probe and not just an ordinary o scope probe.

Comment: actually whatever the example which i gave now, I tested using TINA TI,a simulation software.

Comment: I think you must have made a mistake.